# Call static class method

Tags: java

How can I call static class' method.
I have a parent class like

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
public class parent {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String methodName;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected MethodCall.Params params;

    public static class member {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String value) {
            this.name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call static class' (member) getters and setters method.
I tried by calling

```
parent.member.setName("value")
```

But it is not working. How can I call the setters and getters method which is in the static class ?

Comment: Hey look into http://java2novice.com/java-nested-classes/static-member-class-initialization/ page to get more about how to call static member class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call it like that, because the method with in  static nested class is not static function . its instance function.

```
//Its wrong  
 parent.member.setName("value");

//right way to call
parent.member obj= new parent.member();
obj.setName("value");
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd need an *instance* of `parent.member`, because `setName` is an instance method:

```
// TODO: Follow Java naming conventions for types...
parent.member x = new parent.member();
x.setName("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

change method definitions to:

```
public static String getName()
public static void setName(String value)
```

and field:

```
protected static String name;
```

to use your code for calling. Another way is to instantinate current class (inside parent):

```
member tmp = new member()
```

And then :

```
tmp.setName("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

`setName()` is not an **static** method. 
Hence whenever you want to call this method, you must use instance of an class.

```
parent.member mem = new parent.member();
mem.setName();
```